# Platform independent JavaScript: Check existence of DOM

Tags: javascript, object, window, cross-platform, document

What is the best and safest (not shortest/fastest) solution for (cross-browser/-platform) checking the existence of the `document` object (and maybe the `window` object if necessary)?

```
(function(root, undefined) {

    var document = false;

    if(typeof root.document === "object" && root.document !== null)
        document = root.document;

    // ...

    if(document !== false)
        doMyFancyClientSideStuff();

})(this);
```

Is `typeof window.document` in browsers always `"object"`? Or is there maybe anything like a work-around needed to make sure that our received object is really the DOM type of object, like `window.document instanceof window.Document`, and not just a self made object or what else.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you NEED to do instead of how you already thought of solving it? I can personally only see an issue if you run in a headless browser or IDE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition of "Cross-Browser" is pretty cruicial here. I'd actually recommend to check for the `[[Class]]` property like:

```
Object.prototype.toString.call( root.document );
```

That should return `[object HTMLDocument]` in modern'ish browsers (or `[object Undefined]`). To also include IE8+ on this list, we need to call

```
if( "" + this.document === '[object HTMLDocument]' ) { }
```

This would create a list of

- IE8+
- Chrome
- Firefox
- Safari
- Opera (I don't know, but think so)

IE<8 will always return `[object]` on the `window.document` [[Class]]. This is at least, the most accurate check I can think of. You can of course, also just check something like

```
if( 'document' in this ) { }
```

but that is no guarantee that we are talking about an actuall DOM object, just that there is a property called `document` in the global object.

Comment: Thanks! `"" + this.document` is what I was searching for. I'm doing a cross-browser test for more researching since there is no chance to do this in <IE8.